# When rooting a device, how to check that the update.zip I download is legit?

Tags: rooting, security

I have an Android device (Samsung Galaxy Pocket S5300) which I want to root, because I have used Ubuntu on my PC and notebook for five or six years and I am familiar with doing different maintenance there using root, so I want to have a way to use root-privileges on my smartphone too. I don't have a lot of experience in developing smartphone applications and rooting smartphones, so I need a bit of help.

After a bit of reading, I read that I should download an `update.zip` file, which I should select in the recovery mode.

I read [this thread on XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2365697) where they say I should download an `update.zip` from MediaFire. I downloaded it to my PC and had a look into it and could find the various binaries that I need to be installed (`su`, `busybox`, `superuser.apk`, etc.)

Now I have a question: do I really need to download an `update.zip` from MediaFire, where I don't know what it comes from? The reason I'm worried is that I don't know who has created it and have no real possibility to check if the binaries I will execute are not compromised and have no viruses, etc. I am a bit scared to execute binaries somewhere from the web (with root privileges) where I don't know if they are to be trusted and to be sure that they are no viruses, spyware, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the file is on MediaFire or XDA, you still run the risk of a user putting up a bad file (whether maliciously or incompetently). You have to trust someone unless you decide to make your own ROM from scratch.

You could always open the `update.zip` file and do a cursory look at its contents. And if the poster has a good history, that gives points in their favor. Many posters on XDA host their files on external download tools like MediaFire; it doesn't inherently make the file more suspicious.